# How to extract a specific part of string in a column and assign it to a new column in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to extract a specific part of column in pandas and assign it to a new column. The part that I want to extract is not fixed in a string for eg:
`MC-ABC 2+0/XPIC 2+0` or `MisMatch!MC-ABS 2+0 ::: / XPIC 2+0`.
Here I want to extract only `XPIC`.

I tried using regular expression but could not get the desired result.

Comment: Are you saying you want everything between 2+0 and 2+0? Or is the string after the '/'?  Can you make it clear what exactly you're trying to extract from your strings?

Comment: From the entire string I just need to extract XPIC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [str.extract()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample DataFrame
data = {'column': ['MC-ABC 2+0/XPIC 2+0', 'MisMatch!MC-ABS 2+0 ::: / XPIC 2+0']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Extract the desired part using regular expression and assign it to a new column
df['new_column'] = df['column'].str.extract(r'(\bXPIC\b)')

# Print the DataFrame
print(df)
```

```
        column                           new_column
0  MC-ABC 2+0/XPIC 2+0                      XPIC
1  MisMatch!MC-ABS 2+0 ::: / XPIC 2+0       XPIC
```

Comment: The expected logic doesn't really make sense, this does extract a **fixed** string here

Comment: That's what I wanted